# check if a proxy supports smtp

Tags: c#

I'm just wondering if i have the correct code to check if a proxy supports SMTP or not. I'm not a spammer or anything it just randomly interested me. I Have this for testing:

```
    //host = proxy IP address
    public static void can_mail(string host)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.Body = "Email is working!";
        msg.From = new MailAddress("me@whatever.com");
        msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
        msg.Subject = "Mail Test";
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("myemailaddress@myserver.com"));

        try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = host;
            client.Port = 25;
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            client.Send(msg);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} connected, mail probably works?", host);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Have I missed something here?

Comment: *I'm not a spammer or anything it just randomly interested me.* Now that's [suspiciously specific denial](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SuspiciouslySpecificDenial).

Comment: ok, what about reverse Phycology? I am a spammer!?

Comment: Probably not. If you were, you would not have had any problem testing that code in the wild instead of asking us whether it works or not ;)

Comment: the right answer is, you would need to contact the proxy hoster.

Comment: ah so reverse phycology does work!